# SQL Server 2008::How to use ALTER TABLE to add a new column that has unique number for every unique value in another column

Tags: sql-server-2008, alter-table

To make it more clear, I have a table like this

```
 Batch  domain
 ---------------
  14    xyz.com  
  14    abc.com  
  15    abc.com  
  15    xyz.com
```

I want a 3rd column that has unique number for every domain, doesn't matter which batch they are from.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you would never do this by adding a column. What you need is to add a table for the domains that has an identity field called DomainID. Then the Batch domain table stores the ID not the domain name and it joins to the Domain table to get the names.

Comment: I completely understand what you mean, i would usually do it that way but because of current database condition, I would like to solve this by adding a column instead of creating another table.

Comment: Then the only choice you have is to maintain it through a trigger and make sure to handle race conditions.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, `NEWID()` and `NEWSEQUENTIALID()` can be used.

Note that as a function, Newid can  be called via trigger/stored procedure/query but NEWSEQUENTIALID can only be set as the `DEFAULT` value for a column of type `uniqueidentifier`.

There are limitations on both, and SEQUENTIAL ID can be guessed or cause clusters if blackouts occur, but this can be managed if security is not a concern for the value.

```
ALTER TABLE [Schema_Name].[Table_Name]
ADD DomainID uniqueidentifier DEFAULT (NEWSEQUENTIALID() )
```

While it is dated, [Dave Pinal](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/08/16/sql-server-2005-difference-and-similarity-between-newsequentialid-and-newid/) has a good explanation between the two.

Comment: Added the column data type